# Check if item value exists in Firebase array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
{
  "accounts" : {
    "-account1" : {
      "email" : "test@example.com",
      "name" : "John doe",
      "online" : false,
      "profilePic" : "example.com/img.png",
      "username" : "jonh_doe"
      "tokens" : [ 
        "token11111", 
        "token22222",
        "token33333"]
    },
    "-account2" : {
      "email" : "testymctest@example.com",
      "name" : "Jane doe",
      "online" : false,
      "profilePic" : "example.com/img.png",
      "username" : "jane"
      "tokens" : [ 
        "token44444", 
        "token55555",
        "token66666"]
    }
  }
}
```

My user data is structured as above and I'm trying to determine if -account1 has a token with the value "token11111"

Other Firebase examples suggest using snapshot, but I haven't found an example that drills down into a child element to find a value.

This is what I've tried

```
firebase.database().ref('accounts/-account1/tokens')
.equalTo(newToken)
.once('value')
.then(function(tokens) {
        if (tokens.exists()) {
        //Token already exists
        }
        else{
        //Push new token to db  
        }
    });
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what `tokens` really contains.  Firebase doesn't really have a true array structure.  Go look at your data in the console and you'll see that it's either a delimited string, or key/value pairs with keys that are numbers, or key/value pairs where the tokens are keys, and the values are simply `true`.  Which one are you actually using?

Comment: @DougStevenson they're in key/value pairs. Sorry the Json export of my Firebase db doesn't reflect that

Comment: So it goes '0':'token0', '1':'token1', etc?

Comment: @DougStevenson Yessir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you get an array-like object back from a Firebase snapshot (the keys are numbers starting a 0), you deal with it just like a regular JavaScript array:

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref('/accounts/-account1/tokens');
ref.once('value').then(function(snap) {
  var array = snap.val();
  for (var i in array) {
    var value = array[i]
    console.log(value);
    if (value == 'whatever') { ... }
  }
});
```

This will iterate and print each value.  You can look for any value that you like in that loop.  Or you can `includes(x)` on the array in JavaScript ES2016.